# programmatically feed a kml-file and retrieve/generate a .png-file

Tags: c++, kml

How can I, programmatically, draw a KML-file (routing information on a map) onto a map and then save the result to a .png-file?

What I try to accomplish: a program of mine (written in C++) produces a route. Now I would like this program to emit a .png-file instead with the route draw on it.

I've looked into the google maps api as well as others (e.g. cartagen) but google maps is java-script oriented and cartagen produces html5 output.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use Qt Framework to achive this.
It has great XML support so it should be easy to read KML.
It has support for drawing simple shapes.
It has support for PNGs too.

There is also library called libkml - it can probably help you with manipulating with KML files.

I highly doubt if there is any "Ready to Use" solution.